# Cakephp 3 session issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have setup two different cakephp3 on same server one for front end and second for admin side. for some reason I need to read admin side session in front end but I unable to read the session that I have created in admin side but I able to read same session in admin side. Please help me.

Admin side:

```
$this->request->session()->write('tmp',$temp);
```

Front side:

```
$this->request->session()->read('tmp');
```

Comment: can you check the value 'tmp' in set in the session on backend, before reading it in frondend?

Comment: Is it by chance that the admin application is under `https` and the front end under `http` ? Thus the secured session cookie may not be seen under http. By the way, are your both applications under the same domain ? Again if domains differ session cookies would differ as well.

Comment: thank for your reply. both admin and front end is running on http